# Unit test AspNetCore Controller check HttpStatusCode with ActionResult<T> result

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to check the HttpStatusCode from a call to the controller but I can't figure out how to convert my `ActionResult<T>` to `HttpStatusCodeResult`.

Method from the controller :

```
[Get]
public async Task<ActionResult<PagedResult<PersoDemandLiteResponse>>> GetDemandsByFilterAsync([FromQuery] DemandFilterRequest filter)
    => await this.GetAsync(() => DemandService.GetDemandByFilterAsync(filter), (sources) => sources);
```

Here is my test method (simplified) :

```
... mocking of the services ...

var controller = new DemandController(demandService, organizationService.Object, productService.Object, Mapper.Object);

var request = new DemandFilterRequest { OrganizationId = Guid.NewGuid() };

var result = await controller.GetDemandsByFilterAsync(request);

//I would like to do something like this 
 var action = result as HttpStatusCodeResult;
 var badRequest = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;

 Assert.Equal(badRequest, action.StatusCode);
```

But I get the following error :

> Error  CS0039  Cannot convert type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult>' to 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpStatusCodeResult' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion.

Any idea on how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the method under test returns a bad request as implied by the example code, that would have been something similar to

```
//...

if(...)
    return BadRequest();

//...
```

Then when unit testing, the wrapped result needs to be extracted from the action result

```
//Arrange
//...omitted for brevity

//Act
ActionResult<PagedResult<PersoDemandLiteResponse>> response = 
    await controller.GetDemandsByFilterAsync(request);
    
//Assert
BadRequestResult actual = response.Result as BadRequestResult;    
Assert.NotNull(actual);
int badRequest = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
Assert.Equal(badRequest, actual.StatusCode);
```

Reference [Controller action return types in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types)

Comment: Great, I didn't how to manage to use it like this and yes, the method returns a bad request.